# All values converted to NA while converting character to numeric

Tags: r

When I convert my data frame columns to numeric, all the values become NA

```
offense[,2:13] <- apply(offense[,2:13],2,as.numeric)
```

[The converted data frame.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kF9Si.png)

[Dataframe before conversion.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LSkk.png)

They are all numbers no commas, I have even tried removing white spaces if there are any by chance by using

```
as.data.frame(apply(offense,2,function(x)gsub('\\s+','',x)))
```

but still the values are converted to NA on type conversion with a warning message.

I got the data from a URL (Data Science Cookbook chapter 3)

```
offense <- readHTMLTable(url, encoding = "UTF-8", colClasses="character")[[7]]
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.  Also use `lapply(offense[,2:13], as.numeric)`

Comment: Already tried it, the values are not converted to NA but are changed to some random integers.

Comment: In that case, you need to provide a small reproducible example using `dput` i.e. `dput(droplevels(head(yourdataset)))`

Comment: Share the `url` from which you are getting the data. Why the `colClasses="character"` argument? Quite bizarre, since you want numeric values.

Comment: ' url <- paste("http://sports.yahoo.com/nfl/stats/byteam?group=Offense&cat=Total&conference=NFL&year=season_2013&sort=530&old_category=Total&old_group=Offense")'
thought converting from character to numeric would be easier, didn't work thought

Answer (score 0):

The imported variables are factors, so you have to use, e.g.

```
as.numeric(as.character(offense$`Pts/G`))

apply(offense[, 2:13], 2, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

See `?factor`:

> To transform a factor f to approximately its original numeric values,
>   as.numeric(levels(f))[f] is recommended and slightly more efficient
>   than as.numeric(as.character(f)).

(however, the first way did not work for me, maybe I made a mistake, but the second way with as.numeric(as.character()) works)

Comment: Although your answer did help but the real problem was that there were trailing white spaces in each value which I was able to remove using the `str_trim` function from the `stringr` library.

Comment: Since I had no data from you, I could not know. The data I downloaded from your provided link worked w/o any string modifications.